# How to perform a join in SQL Server without using tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two lists and I want to see what the two lists DON'T have in common. For example:

```
List1:
'a','b','c','123'

List2:
'd','e','f','a','asd','c'
```

I want output to be:

```
'b','123','d','e','f','asd'
```

Something like this?

```
select * from ('a','b','c','123')
join ('d','e','f','a','asd','c')
on ???
```

Is there a pure SQL Server solution for this without using tables?

Comment: Are these lists hard-coded in your query?

Comment: @stevepastelan yes they sure are

Comment: Does the output need to be six separate columns or can it be a string?

Comment: @AaronBertrand string is fine!!

Comment: And do you have control over how the list is scripted?

Comment: So for example the list could be `a,b,c,123` instead of `'a','b','c','123'`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  yes thats correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have control over the lists, I would just make them table variables:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (str varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @a
VALUES
('a'),
('b')...

DECLARE @b table (str varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @b
VALUES
...

(SELECT str FROM @a
EXCEPT 
SELECT str FROM @b)
UNION
(SELECT str FROM @b
EXCEPT
SELECT str FROM @a)
```

Comment: You can probably process them as strings using a splitter function or something, but this will be easiest I think.

Comment: what do you think of stevepalen answers

Comment: I think it's doesn't compile :)  He's inserting a single row into two CTEs, so it might work as well, but it'll need to be uglier syntax using a `UNION` between each row

Comment: why did you use EXCEPT instead of join?

Comment: It's a set comparison operator, and syntax is simpler.  You could potentially do a couple of `JOIN`s to get the same effect but this is more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Given this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings ( @List NVARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item FROM (
           SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
           FROM (
               SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List,',', '</i><i>') 
                    + '</i>').query('.')) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)
       ) AS y WHERE Item IS NOT NULL);
GO
```

You can do it with a full outer join:

```
DECLARE 
    @list1  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'a,b,c,123', 
    @list2  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'd,e,f,a,asd,c',
    @output NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @output += N',' + COALESCE(l1.Item, l2.Item) 
  FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@list1) AS l1
  FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings(@list2) AS l2
  ON l1.Item = l2.Item 
  WHERE l1.Item IS NULL OR l2.Item IS NULL;

SELECT STUFF(@output, 1, 1, N'');
```

Or similar to @JNK's:

```
DECLARE 
    @list1  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'a,b,c,123', 
    @list2  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'd,e,f,a,asd,c',
    @output NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

;WITH l1 AS (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@list1)), 
      l2 AS (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@list2))
SELECT @output += N',' + Item 
FROM ( (SELECT Item FROM l1 EXCEPT SELECT Item FROM l2)
        UNION
       (SELECT Item FROM l2 EXCEPT SELECT Item FROM l1)) AS x;

SELECT STUFF(@output, 1, 1, N'');
```

And probably a variety of other ways too. If order matters, it's going to be a little more complex, but still possible.

Comment: why did you use EXCEPT instead of join?

Comment: Sorry, swapped the code samples, that's all. I just wrote everything except the function, which I had written an almost identical one in 2010, which I probably pieced together from myself and/or the collective much earlier : https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup.aspx

Comment: פיצול מחרוזת של ערכים המופרדים בפסיקים לסט- זה אתגר שיכול לצוץ כשעובדים עם מידע המגיע בקבצי טקסט, או

Comment: @AaronBertrand google translate tells me that's hebrew for `Splitting a string of comma-separated values ​​set - it's a challenge that can arise when working with data coming from text files, or`

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to accomplish this. To filter the values from a list you need to have them as rows. So you would end up with something like:

```
SELECT col FROM (
SELECT 'a' as col
UNION
SELECT 'b'
UNION
SELECT 'c') t

WHERE col NOT IN ('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
with
list1(j) as (select 'a' union select 'b'),
list2(j) as (select 'b' union select 'c')

select coalesce(list1.j, list2.j)
from list1 full join list2
on list1.j = list2.j
where (list1.j is null or list2.j is null)
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.

Comment: steve can you make it compile"? JNK says He's inserting a single row into two CTEs, so it might work as well, but it'll need to be uglier syntax using a UNION between each row

Comment: Ah - too bad. I don't have a SQL Server handy, but it runs as written on DB2. I was hoping the syntax would be compatible :)

Comment: @stevepastelan if you change the `values` statements to `select 'a' union select 'b' union...` it should parse OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to insert the values into 2 variable tables.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Value VARCHAR(1))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Value VARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Value) VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Value) VALUES ('b')

INSERT INTO @Table2 (Value) VALUES ('b')
INSERT INTO @Table2 (Value) VALUES ('c')
```

Then perform some set operations on the 2 tables.

```
DECLARE @TableUnion TABLE (Value VARCHAR(1))
DECLARE @TableIntersection TABLE (Value VARCHAR(1))
DECLARE @TableExcept TABLE (Value VARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @TableUnion 
SELECT * FROM
    ((SELECT * FROM @Table1)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM @Table2)) U

INSERT INTO @TableIntersection 
SELECT * FROM
    ((SELECT * FROM @Table1)
    INTERSECT
    (SELECT * FROM @Table2)) I

INSERT INTO @TableExcept
SELECT * FROM
    ((SELECT * FROM @TableUnion)
    EXCEPT
    (SELECT * FROM @TableIntersection)) E
```

The result set of the final select statement will contain 'a' and 'c'.  Which can be concatenated into a single string as follows.

```
DECLARE @ExceptString VARCHAR(3)

SELECT @ExceptString = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @ExceptString IS NULL THEN Value
        ELSE @ExceptString + ',' + Value
    END
FROM @TableExcept
```

Comment: +1 to compensate, though isn't your output is opposite of what is requested?

Comment: Nope. He wants the XOR of the two lists. Thanks for the pity vote, though :-)

Comment: He said he wanted the output to be `'b','123','d','e','f','asd'` not `'a','c'`... he also wanted them to be a string, not two values in a column.

Comment: In my example, I shrunk the sets for simplicity's sake.  Set 1 consists of {'a', 'b'} and set 2 consists of {'b', 'c'}.  The XOR of these 2 sets is {'a', 'c'}.  The concatenation of these values back into a single string is some what trivial but I can add it if needed.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think it's more helpful in general to use the same data as the OP, especially when your shrunk data happens to contradict the requirements (maybe change it to `apple, bear, cat` to differentiate).